# Coordinate system in Map&Guide

Tags: coordinate-system, mapguide

One of my customers is evaluating transport planning software Map&Guide (http://www.mapandguide.com/) and what we require is to get the transport route data from their file to Garmin navigation device.

The problem is that the M&G file contains coordinates in some system that I do not recognize and I would like to ask your help to sort it out.

Slice from the M&G *.BCR file:

```
[COORDINATES]
STATION1=2751856,8265742
STATION2=4506233,9477610
STATION3=4183918,7501674
STATION4=3393742,6515209
STATION5=5539499,4914891
STATION6=4983102,5109208
STATION7=3655214,4850900
STATION8=1503212,6863049
STATION9=-49653,6695422
[DESCRIPTION]
STATION1=EST 10148,At Tallinn,Pärnu Maantee,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION2=RUS,At Archangel'sk,,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION3=RUS ,At Moskva / Kitaj-Gorod,Bol'shoj Cherkasskij pereulok,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION4=UA 01001,At Kyjiv,Esplanadna Vulytsia,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION5=AZ ,At Baki,Nanman Narimanov Avenue,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION6=GE ,At T'bilis? / Avlabari,Ketevan Camebulis Kuca,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION7=TR 31600,Ankara / Dörtyol,,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION8=D 12529,Berlin-Schönefeld-Terminal a,Flughafen,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
STATION9=GB TW6 1,London Heathrow-Terminal 4 Arrival,Salisbury Road,0,,0,0,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,0,,0,0.0000000000,0.00,0.00,,0,0,0,0
```

The coordinates should match the locations in second section. Being from Estonia, I do not recognize 2751856,8265742 pair as anywhere near me.

Any help on the matter or any hints where to dig on are much appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like **Universal Transverse Mercator**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system

http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/fmt_bcr.html

[image]

Estonia is in UTM 34V (Gulf of Riga) & 35V

Answer (score 2):

I think the coordinates are in the spherical Mercator used by Bing maps and Google maps, NOT UTM. UTM coords normally are 6 digits in the easting. EPSG uses 3857 (as does Esri starting with ArcGIS 10) for the well-known ID. Esri used to use either 102113 or 102100 and others around the internet use 900913 ("google").